# Trouble download source from a web page

Tags: c#, download, webclient, httprequest, html

Im trying to download the source code for this webpage for a school project using c#.
this is the page im trying to get:
http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1650

I have tried code such as

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1650");
```

and by using

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1650");
```

and neither methods are getting me the page source. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "source", you mean the HTML, right?

Answer (score 4):

**using HttpWebRequest.Create**

```
try
{
    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1650");
    req.Method = "GET";

    string source;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        source = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Log the exception 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

**Using DownloadString**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString("http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1650");
```

Above methods are working fine for me. Check the exception if any..

Comment: I would have upvoted this exception that your example uses `ex.Message`. It should be `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: normally we not show the full exception to user but log the full exception. that's why I use the exception.Message. In this case we can show the full exception to find the issue. Thanks.. Updated my answer

Comment: Upvoted. My feeling is that if you're going to show exception handling, then show the newbies how to use `ex.ToString()`. Otherwise, then think that `ex.Message` is enough information.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
string sourceCode = "";
Uri site = new Uri("http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1650");
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(site);
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII)){
    sourceCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The "using" statement will close your streams for you. NOTE: Calling close on a stream will also call class on any streams it is using, this is why you only need the single using statement

Comment: -1: Perhaps you could edit your answer to show correct use of `using`? I would then remove the downvote.

Comment: @John Saunders, how about that?

Comment: Good enough. You should really break out the GetResponse and GetResponseStream calls, but this will do.